# Espresso: Check if one of checks are true

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

How to check in ellegant way if one of checks are true? My situation: I click on SendToken button, if I have tokens I can send it(here I need enter email and check if DialogFragment appeared), else I need to check if DialogFragment which informs me that I have no tokens appeared.
The test below checks only situation when I have tokens:

```
onView(withId(R.id.btnSendToken)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.etEmail)).perform(typeText(EMAIL));
        onView(withId(R.id.btnSend)).perform(click());
        onView(withText(
                activityActivityTestRule
                        .getActivity()
                        .getString(R.string.text_successfully_send) + " " + EMAIL))
                .inRoot(isDialog())
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        onView(withText(DIALOG_TOKEN_SENT_TEXT)).perform(click());
```

The problem: if I have no tokens left test fails. How to check 2 conditions at once.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What you want is a wrong attitude. For different use cases you should make two different tests. One for "no tokens", one for "have tokens".

Comment: @Psytho ok, thank you